# Pathos.multiprocessing's Pool appears to be nonlocal?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pathos

A code of mine does

```
from pathos.multiprocessing import ProcessingPool
def myFunc(something):
    thispool = ProcessingPool(nodes=Result.cores)
    listOfResults = thispool.map(something)
    return listOfResults

for i in range(1000):
    myFunc(i)
```

Now, in my actual more involved code, memory usage just kept growing. The code should take nothing, but if I run it with 12 cores, these 12 cores will initially take almost 1mb memory, but over the runtime of several hours, each of which will take several GB.

So, I thought that pool would leak memory, and that I better close it after each iteration:

```
def myFunc(something):
    thispool = ProcessingPool(nodes=Result.cores)
    listOfResults = thispool.map(something)
    thispool.close()
    thispool.join()
    return listOfResults
```

However, now, after several iterations, I get

```
ValueError: Pool not running
```

at the `this pool.map()` line. If I create a new

```
test = ProcessingPool(nodes=4)
```

and try to run `test.map()`, I get the same error. Which is weird, I have  initialized a new variable... does `pathos.processing.ProcessingPool` have the feature of a unique process pool, and if I close one, I close *all*?

What's the correct way of implementing a `pathos.multiprocessing.ProcessingPool` inside a loop, without memory leakage?

**When I instead use `multiprocessing.Pool`, the problem does not arise.**

Answer (score 5):

It turns out that indeed, through some backend magic, `pathos` prevents multiple instances of the *same type of* pool to be initialized.

To prevent leakage, one can do at the end of each iteration

```
thispool.terminate()
thispool.restart()
```

Comment: I'm the `pathos` author.  This is definitely the case.